# How do you join a server to an Active Directory (domain)?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Need to launch a new ASP.NET site on this server but need to be joined to our Active Directory domain, anyone know how this is done?

Comment: This is not a programming question, is it?

Comment: should be moved to serverfault :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The administrator of your domain would normally do that, and if he didn't know how, he'd consult [a Microsoft Knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295017) (and if he was a she, she'd just know)

Comment: I think we all are; I'm kinda surprised this one hasn't been closed with "belongs on serverfault" yet.

Comment: Thing is, one need a decent amount of rep to vote for close, and to get that many rep points, one can answer these kinds of easy but perhaps not really programming related questions.. oh the irony ^^

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS.  Up through Windows Server 2003 you need to:

- Right-click on "My Computer" (on the server) and select properties
- Select the "Computer Name" tab
- Click "Change..."
- In "Member of" select the "Domain" radio button
- Enter the name of your domain
- A popup will then appear asking you to provide the credentials of someone that has access to join a computer to the domain (ask your administrator about this one - many organizations allow employees to join computers to domains)
- Reboot your machine when it prompts you to.

If it's Windows Server 2008 you'll have to select "Advanced System Settings" from the menu on the left after you select "Properties" on "My Computer".

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean your application server or your database server?  If your application isn't in active directory, it's most likely not on the domain.  If you have a Sys or Network Admin, talk to them.