# disable netbios in c#

Tags: c#, .net

how can i make netbios be disabled using C#

heres the sample image i want to do
[image]

Also, can i do it on every network adapter in my PC? how can i also select the adapter that i like, then set it. is there a way to keep it permanently disabled? thanks

I currently tried to code, but i cant find any class, or any method that can actually manipulate the settings in my network adapter. I hope you could help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394572%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for this. I don't have an answer for your specific requirement, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183759/programmatically-join-windows-machine-to-ad-domain) may guide you in the right direction.